# Out-of-Date MS SQL Server 2014 instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

Could you give me some advice on the best practice to update a SQL Server 2014 instance that is on version 12.00.2000.00? Can I install the Service Packs or do I need all of the cumulative updates as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install the most recent service pack, then install the latest cumulative update.

According to [SQL Server Builds](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.ca/), the most recent Service Pack for SQL Server 2014 is currently [SP2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53168).

[CU10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4052725) is the most recent Cumulative Update.

Ensure you take a backup of your databases onto physically different media, and do this in a non-production environment to test the change prior to doing this to your production SQL Server.